# Even with ::from I'm getting expected type parameter A error

Tags: rust

Given this function,

```rust
fn incr<A: std::ops::AddAssign>(mut foo: A) -> A {
    foo += A::from(1);
    foo
}
```

I'm getting,

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:20
  |
1 | fn incr<A: std::ops::AddAssign>(mut foo: A) -> A {
  |         - this type parameter
2 |     foo += A::from(1);
  |                    ^ expected type parameter `A`, found integer
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `A`
                       found type `{integer}`
  = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
  = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Generally you should use `into()`, this make the error more clear https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23eb043e2af9c8f31f53d0a1e1b008f8 or complete form... https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df2e428f38c4598c080751d72164fe4a very verbose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that `A` has a trait bound that requires that it implements `From<u8>`:

```
fn incr<A: std::ops::AddAssign + From<u8> > (mut foo: A) -> A {
    foo += A::from(1);
    foo
}
```